Insert into table based on multiple conditions in postgreSQL
I am new to Postgresql as well as SQL and I'm unable to think for an optimal solution to achieve this.
I have users table:



user_id(PK)
first_name
user_type




1
John
staff


9
Matthew
customer



services table:



service_id(PK)
service_name




1
Pumbing service



quote table (which is empty right now):



quote_id(PK)
customer_id(FK)
service_id(FK)
message











now I want to insert value into the quotes table if both of these conditions satisfy

if there exists a user with the provided user_id = 9(customer id) and its user_type = 'customer'
if there exists service in the services table i.e service_id = 1

If these conditions satisfy then I want to do something like
INSERT INTO quotes(customer_id, service_id, message)
VALUES(9, 1, 'Require plumbing services for kitchen renovation.')


You can use a single query
INSERT INTO quotes (customer_id, service_id, message)
SELECT @user_id, @service_id, @message
FROM users u
JOIN services s ON s.service_id = @service_id)
WHERE u.user_id = @user_id;

